# Issue with Node "firebase-admin" - MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am using Nodejs as my backend and have firebase-admin to add and update documents to firebase. While creating a document in localhost its clearly able to create and update documents.

Now I have uploaded the same thing to the server and installed everything. On creating a document. I receive this error through winston.

> {"code":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND","level":"info","message":"Error creating order: "}

Can't seem to understand what exactly is a issue here.

**Environment:-**

1. Nodejs v8.1.1
2. Express with MongoDB
3. Using **Babel** build.

Please advise.

Comment: i have a similiar err {"code":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND"}. Any ideas so far ?

Comment: @ramstein yea was able to find the issue after debugging somehow on server. My local system had a different version of node-gyp and the server had a different version so I had to download the specific build and install it to the location.